# floating div keeps sliding below other floating div

Tags: css, html

My site consists of a side menu div and a main content div. I've floated the divs left and used percentages so that the columns fill the entire page. However I'm also using min-widths because I want the side menu to be no smaller than 205px wide and the main content to be no smaller than 780px. The site needs to be no smaller than 985px wide however I still want the content to be flexible enough to fill the screen.

My problem is when I resize the window (less than 985px wide) the main content div moves underneath the side menu. Where am I going wrong?, The div should stay in the same position, next to the side menu, but the horizontal scroll bar should kick in. The content should then fill the screen.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef5f3/1/)

THE HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="side-bar">
        <p>side bar</p>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">

        <div id="content">
            <p>some content</p>
        </div>    

    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

THE CSS:

```
body 
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:100%;
font-family:Arial;
}

p 
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#wrapper 
{
width:100%;
min-width:985px; /*site no smaller than 985px wide*/
height:auto;
}

#side-bar 
{
width:15%;
min-width:205px; /*nav sidebar no smaller than 205px wide*/
min-height:672px;
background-color:Gray;
float:left;
}

#main-content
{
width:85%;
min-width:780px;
min-height:672px;
background-color:Maroon;
float:left;
}

#content 
{
width:740px;
height:500px;
background-color:#ccc;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted the answer but for some reason its now disappeared so I can't take credit for fixing the issue.

I created a wrapper that had a min-width of 985px. I then used percentage values for the side and main content divs 15% & 85% respectively. However I didn't take into account that its 15% and 85% of the 985px wrapper.

My side bar was 15% wide with a min-width of 205px, however 15% of 985px is only 147.25px so the extra pixels was forcing the main content div below the side bar.

Hope that makes sense? Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your main content div goes below the menu div is due to the way that the box model works. If you change your main content div to be a inline-block, it will stay to the right of the menue. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X64R5/) to show you how you can do it.

```
#main-content
{
   display:inline-block
   width:85%;
   min-width:780px;
   min-height:672px;
   background-color:Maroon;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me, unfortunately none of the suggestions have worked. As soon as you start to shink the browser window the main content div still moves underneath the side bar

Comment: @user2982873 That's weird, the jsfiddle works fine for me in Chrome and firefox. Did you try clicking the jsfiddle to see the results or just tried the pasted css?

Answer (score 0):

Blocks floated to the same side only stay next to each other if there is enough horizontal space.

If I really wanted a horizontal scrollbar, I'd experiment with table layout (display: table-row, display: table-cell).

Answer (score 0):

Create a div after the main-content div and give it a class of 'clearfix' and the following style:

```
    .clearfix{
        clear:both;
    }
```

I think the problem might be that you are not clearing the floats, which is why you container div (wrapper) is messing up.